# RoR: friendly_id unique for user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, friendly-id

I have a website that has works on the premise:

`example.com/user_id/news/slug-for-article`

By default, I have enabled unique slugs for articles, however I would like to have slugs unique per user, across all users.

The non-uniqueness is handled by using `@user.articles.friendly.find(param)`.

How can I set this up so it ensures uniqueness, but only for a defined attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [friendly_id](https://github.com/FriendlyId/friendly_id).

It would look like this:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  belongs_to :user

  friendly_id :name, use: :scoped, scope: :user, slug_column: :permalink
```

In case someone picks the same article name, `friendly_id` will calculate a `slug` that doesn't clash with an existing one.

So, for example:

1. Article with id #1 named "Hello" would have permalink `/user_id/news/hello`
2. Article with id #2 named also "Hello" would have permalink `/user_id/news/hello-2`

If you don't want to use that gem, you can just use `Rails` validations.

It'd look like this:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  belongs_to :user

  validates_uniqueness_of :permalink, scope: :user_id
```

Good old [validates_uniqueness_of](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of).

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but this is what I am already doing. I need the slug to be unique depending on the relation

Comment: And `validates_uniqueness_of :permalink, scope: :user_id` doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

AIf you have a has_many through: association you could store the slug in the third model... it's the only place where  you can store data unique to both the user and article.

```
    @user.articles_users.friendly.find(param).each do |association|
      Articles.find(association.article_id)
    end
```